# Surface charge density for an off-centre charge in a spherical shell?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

How would I evaluate the surface charge density on the inner and outer surface of a neutral, spherical, conducting shell which has an off-centre charge $q$ inside? I believe that we can not use the method of image charges since even though we know the potential of the shell is constant we do not know its value; it is not even fixed (unlike a grounded shell).

Comment: Gauss law should help...

Comment: @danimal I think I can only use Gauss's to determine the net charge on each surface rather then the charge density at a given point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a grounded conducting shell, it is [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges#Reflection_in_a_conducting_sphere) that the method of images can be used to calculate how the total charge $-q$ on the inner surface is distributed. The solution is given in the wikipedia link above.

Now, you ask what happens if the the potential of the shell is fixed, but not necessarily zero. The electric field inside the conductor must still be zero. Using Gauss's law and a surface that is inside the conductor we know that there then must still be a charge $-q$ distributed over the inner surface in some way. To conserve charge there must now also be a charge $+q$ distributed over the outer surface.

We know that the electric field lines leaving the outer surface of a conductor must be perpendicular to that surface. But for a spherical outer surface, the only way this can be arranged and keep the outer surface as an equipotential is if the charge $+q$ is distributed uniformly over that surface. This spherically symmetric arrangement of charge contributes no net electric field inside the conducting shell or in its interior. i.e. the electric field *outside* the conducting shell will be exactly equivalent to that of a positive charge at the centre of the shell. Furthermore, as the contribution of this charge to the field inside the shell is zero, then it cannot alter the electric field deduced using the method of images for a grounded shell.

As the electric field at the inner surface of the shell is unchanged, then the surface distribution of charge must also be unchanged.

**Therefore nothing changes about the inner shell charge surface distribution if the shell is not grounded**.

Comment: How did you conclude this *"But for a spherical outer surface, the only way this can be arranged and keep the outer surface as an equipotential is if the charge +q is distributed uniformly over that surface."* ?

Comment: @Sidd The electric field parallel to the surface must be zero, otherwise the charges would move to make it so. Any anisotropy in the charge distribution on a spherical surface would give rise to an electric field. And there can't be a contribution from charge inside because the electric field in the conductor is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the method of images because uniqueness of the solution is guaranteed when you Know the total charge of an equipotential surface without knowing the value of the potential itself

I'll summarize a procedure to obtain the correct answer:
Application of Gauss law tells us that there must be total charge -q on the inner surface then because of charge conservation there must be total charge q on the outer surface. How do we know the surface density of this charge? We solve the boundary value problem por the regions exterior to the outer shell and interior to the inner shell.
For the exterior region we simply have $V_{ext}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}$ which gives a constant surface density

For the interior region we use the method of images. Place a charge outside the inner shell of magnitud $q'=-\frac{d}{a}q$ at a distance from the center of $d=\frac{a^2}{\delta}$ where $\delta$ is the distance from center to the charge placed inside and "a" is the shell radius.

The physical reason for the internal shell charge density not being uniform is that a uniform surface density can never compensate the potential of an off-centre point charge

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the boundary value problem to be used to determine $V_ext$?

Comment: You have to find a solution of laplace eq Knowing the total charge on the suface and also knowing that the surface is equipotencial.Under this conditions you know there exist only one solution(unless a constant)

Comment: It is quite easy because outside the conductor the equation for the electric potential is $\Delta V =0$ because there are no charges. More than this you know that over a circle centered in the origin the potential is constant (the boundary of the conductor). Thus the problem has spherical symmetry and the Laplace equation becomes an ordinary, homogenous, differential equation that you can solve easily.

Comment: $V_{ext}=\frac q {4πϵ_0r}$ will give a constant charge density only if the charges inside the outer surface, i.e., the off-center charge and inner shell charge density, contribute nothing to the potential. I can't understand why won't they contribute anything.

Comment: You are right may be it is not easy to understand why they don't contribute, I will let you think about it however I'll note that the solution is mathematically correct, and that is precisely the beauty and utility of the unicity theorem

Comment: @facenian: The only way I can think of the inner charges not contributing is if the outer charge density is uniform. But that itself can only be proved if we know that the inner charges don't contribute. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sidd:The inner charge density compensates the inner point charge irrespective of what happens outside, this is consequence of Coulomb law and we can also say it is a geometrical fact and, although it is not obvious, we can accept it as a reasonable assumption, I don't know a rigorous proof for this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can still use the method of image charges - the image charge will be in the inversion point - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges#Reflection_in_a_conducting_sphere

Comment: I am convinced that method of image charges will NOT work in this situation. The method of image charges requires the potential on the boundary to be known, a requirement for uniqueness theorem for which this method is based. The sphere they use on the wiki page is grounded so we know the potential is 0 and thus uniqueness theorem holds.  This is not we we have here.

Comment: You can just define one shell to be at zero potential. But then the other shell might still be problematic.

Comment: @Joseph: "Alternatively, application of this corollary to the differential form of Gauss' Law shows that in a volume V surrounded by conductors and containing a specified charge density ρ, the electric field is uniquely determined if the total charge on each conductor is given." -same source as in my answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Maybe you should first solve the problem for the interior of the shell, then for the exterior of the shell, but I believe in both cases you can use the image charge method with inversion.

Comment: @Sebastian Riese: Please see my second comment.

Comment: @akhmeteli Since the charges are free to move around inside the conductor, we neither have a specified charge density-this is after all what we are trying to find.

Comment: @Joseph: How is this different from other cases where the image charge method is used?

Comment: @akhmeteli when you use the method of image charges it will always say a grounded conductor or give you a specific value of the potential on the conductor surface. Or as you pointed out, you can also do it if you have a known charge density. In the case we have the potential is not specified and is totally determined by the location of the charge. Granted, it would be a completely different story if the sphere was grounded, but it is not. We have a fixed amount of charge on the sphere (i.e. overall none) but the distribution of this charge is not specified and is what we are trying to find.

Comment: @Joseph: I believe you are mixing up the charge density in the body of the conductor (the spherical shell) and the charge density inside the volume surrounded by the conductor, which volume is mentioned in my quote from Wikipedia. We do know the charge density inside the volume - there is just one charge off center there. I think when you say "the charges are free to move around inside the conductor" you mean the charges within the body of the conductor, as charges cannot move inside the volume surrounded by the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Jeffries's answer is correct, but here's another way to see it.  Consider two solutions to Laplace's/Poisson's equation:

1. $V_1(\vec{r})$ is the solution (in all space) for a spherical conducting shell at potential $V_0$, with $V \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$.
2. $V_2(\vec{r})$ is the solution (in all space) for a grounded spherical conducting shell with an off-center charge $+q$ inside.

Obviously $V_1(\vec{r})$ is just $V_0 R/r$ outside the sphere and $V_0$ inside;  $V_2(\vec{r}) = 0$ outside the shell, and can be found inside the shell via the method of images as noted above.

Now consider the solution $V(\vec{r}) = V_1 + V_2$.  This has the property that the potential is a constant $V_0$ on the shell, goes to zero at infinity, and has the charge distribution corresponding to an off-center charge inside.  But the boundary conditions (and sources) of the original problem are just a specific case of these boundary conditions.  To relate the constant potential $V_0$ to the charge magnitude $q$, we can just use Gauss's Law, with the usual result that $V_0 = q/(4 \pi \epsilon_0 R)$.

Comment: Why $V_2(r)=0$ outside the shell?

Comment: For the second setup, the sphere is grounded, i.e., $V_2(R) = 0$.  This then implies that $V_2 = 0$ for all $r > R$.